# What are the default parameters of `\titleformat{\command}`?

Tags: titlesec

For example, what is the default `format` for `command`=`\chapter`?

```
\titleformat{〈command 〉}[〈shape〉]{〈format〉}{〈label 〉}{〈sep〉}{〈before-code〉}[〈after-code〉]
```

I tried this:

```
grep 'titleformat{name=\\chapter' titlesec.sty
```

(and its abbreviated version), but to no avail.

Man:  https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "default" here. The `titlesec` doc states (§8.2) that the `\chapter` of standard classes is roughly equivalent to `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}`.

Comment: @campa "I am not sure what you mean by "default" here."→the ones that are in effect if you don't override them with `titleformat`. In hindsight I shouldn't have expected to find them in `titlesec.sty`, I presume that's built into the LaTeX engine. Still, where would one find them?

Comment: The notion of 'default' here doesn't really make sense, since the headings settings are set by the particular document class you are using.  `titlesec` just provides users simple means to modify them; the classes themselves don't usually use `titlesec` to format the headings.

Comment: @AlanMunn `titlesec.sty` says: "we get the shape -- if not defined it loads
% the corresponding file" and there's a check for `*.tss`. I'm not finding any...

Comment: @Erwann The `.tss` files are for user defined shapes; the ones that `titlesec` defines are all defined directly in the package itself. But again, `titlesec` doesn't do anything with an existing style unless you override its format yourself.

Comment: @AlanMunn Would you know where to find the specification of a tss file?

Comment: @Erwann The `.tss` file isn't even mentioned in the documentation, so the only real documentation is in the package code itself. A shape `myshape` would be defined in the `.tss` file as a macro with the name `\ttlh@myshape` with 8 arguments:  `{format}{label}{sep}{before}{after}{left}{right}{title}`. You'd need to dig into the existing code quite a bit to see how all of those arguments work.